# How to know which user is connected to the OpenVPN Server?

Tags: openvpn

I'd like to learn which user is connected to the OpenVPN server and the user is authenticated through certification. How can I do that?

Is that possible to match the users and their certifications with the help of scripts?

Comment: `match the users and their certifications` - Uhm, don't your certificates include a useful subject and cn value that identifies the user that owns them?  That is certainly logged.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to check who's currently connected.

```
management 127.0.0.1 5094 /etc/openvpn/.manage_passwd
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status_1194.log
```

Check the man page http://openvpn.net/man.html for the directives:

```
management
status
status-version
```

Comment: Your answer is enough for my question. I need another thing that is the list of mac addresses of connected clients. May i find that somewhere in the management?